# In PHP, how do I convert the string representation of a 64 bit unsigned integer to a signed 64 bit integer?

Tags: php, 64-bit

So here is my situation. I have an application that generates a timestamp as an unsigned 64 bit value. This gets passed to a PHP website as an XML file and parsed from the XML file as a string. I now want to store this value in a PostgreSQL database that doesn't understand unsigned integers (because PostgreSQL just doesn't - go figure) so I need to solve this by casting to a signed 64 bit integer. I can then recast to an unsigned 64 bit integer after getting the value back out of the database.

I have tried the following code:

```
$i64 = unpack('q', pack('Q', $timestamp));

echo "Timestamp " . $timestamp . " = ";
print_r($i64[1]);
echo "<br>";
```

This gives the following output for an input string of "10223372036854775807":

```
Timestamp 10223372036854775807 = 9223372036854775807
```

I really hate when functions don't do what the documentation says they do.

For reference, I picked that value because 9223372036854775807 is the largest signed 64 bit integer value, and I just incremented the first digit to get a bigger number. I get the same output with an input string of "9223372036854775808" where I increment the last digit instead of the first one.

I am guessing that PHP doesn't understand the concept of unsigned integers very well either, and is converting the input to `pack()` to a 64 bit signed integer before packing it, and limiting the value to the maximum value possible.

I tried casting to `unsigned long long` too:

```
$u64 = (unsigned long long)$timestamp;
```

but got:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'long' (T_STRING)
```

Comment: Do you expect to receive timestamps that can't fit inside 63 bits?

Comment: As Manuel in Fawlty Towers once famously said..."Eventually!" (imagine it said with a bad Spanish accent). I write my code to be robust, not to die horribly in 30 years, or however long it might be, with a hideously obscure bug because I was lazy.

Comment: Ok so it is just 20 digits and can only be read as strings in PHP (no unsigned integers in PHP either). But if you have the string "18446744073709551615" you can store it as decimal(20,0) in pgsql and still be able to do math on it.

Comment: @Salman Nice. I'll give that a go. I have other databases with timestamps that I might need to retrofit with the `decimal` data type. I skimmed over that datatype originally because I was wary of the weak typing implied, and the potential issues it might cause.

Comment: @salman That works perfectly. Thankyou so much.